# How to change the text of Label from another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

It is a cross threaded operation in windows application done in c#, How can i change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a delegate and invoke...

```
private delegate void SetLabelSub(string NewText);
private void SetLabel(string NewText)
{
 if (this.InvokeRequired()) {
  SetLabelSub Del = new SetLabelSub(SetLabel);
  this.Invoke(Del, new object[] { NewText });
 } else {
  SomeLabel.Text = NewText;
 }
}
```

Then you can just call `SetLabel("New Text Here")` from any thread

Comment: How roundabout. Just write `Invoke(new Action(() => SomeLabel.Text = NewText));`. The performance impact of doing the invoke when not strictly necessary is negligible, and in 99% of the cases the programmer already knows that it’s always gonna be called from another thread anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a method which you can call from any thread:

```
private void SetLabel(string newText)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() => SomeLabel.Text = NewText));
}
```

Then you can just call `SetLabel("Update the label, please")` from any thread.

However, your question title states “from another **Form**” rather than “from another **thread**”, so it is unclear what you actually mean. You don’t need multithreading if you just want to have multiple forms. You should use threads only for tasks, e.g. downloading a file, copying a file, calculating a value, etc., but not for Forms.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a more general method to change the Text property of *any* control in your form like:

```
private void SetText(Control control, string text)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
         this.Invoke(new Action<Control>((c) => c.Text = text),control);
    else
        control.Text = newText; 
}
```

This will work for labels, buttons, etc, from either the UI thread or any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with threads you need to use the form.`Invoke()` method, assuming you're passing the form instance into the other form.roughly

```
Form form1 = new Form()
Form form2 = new Form();
form2.CallingForm = form1; // make this property or what ever
```

inside form2 add some code like

```
form1.Invoke(someDelagate, value);
```

I don't do winforms that often but if you google form.Invoke you'll get some good examples of how to do cross thread operations.

Comment: Well there ya go, the next post show you how to write invoke methods.